Can k6 be use to generate continuous load
Our perf environment runs 24/7 and we have Gatling scripts generating load.
We would like to port to Grafana k6 but I cant find any options to set the VU and run forever.  Each executor seems to define a test run that must end.
Is it really a hard limitation of k6 runners that they have a limited life span?   Naturally we can make them long runs and bonce the pods periodically but that will generate blips in our graphs and errors.

A year has 8760 hours, so k6 run -d 8760h theoretically keeps the test running for a full year (-d 8784h if you have a leap year, -d 87600h to run for 10 years). I'm only afraid that it will run out of memory sooner or later. There's an open k6 GitHub issue about running tests infinitely which suggests to use the externally-controlled executor, which supports duration: 0 to mean "infinite"

You can use the externally-controlled executor to run a test indefinitely:
import { sleep } from 'k6';

export const options = {
  scenarios:  {
    default: {
      executor: 'externally-controlled',
      duration: '0s', // infinite duration
      vus: 1,
    },
  },
};

export default function() {
  console.log('.');
  sleep(1)
}

Logs at startup:
     scenarios: (100.00%) 1 scenario, 1 max VUs, 0s max duration (incl. graceful stop):
              * default: Externally controlled execution with 1 VUs, 1 max VUs, infinite duration

